# Handshake inactivity timeout - mysql using sqltools

Tags: mysql, sqltools

I am using SQL tools however I keep getting this error. I have changed the connection to 5000 but I keep getting this error. I don't know if this is a syntax error, sqltools error, or a MySQL error.

here is my code

```
--@block
CREATE TABLE Main(
id INT PRIMARY Key,
title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
body TEXT NOT NULL,
mainimageurl VARCHAR(255),
);
```

the error

```
Handshake inactivity timeout
```

it's running on port 3305, using xprotocol. and have opened the udp port

I appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an extra comma after `mainimageurl VARCHAR(255),`. It should be:

```
CREATE TABLE Main(
id INT PRIMARY Key,
title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
body TEXT NOT NULL,
mainimageurl VARCHAR(255)
);
```

I'm not familiar with SQLtools, never used it but usually this type of error is immediately returned [as you can see in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f8ea071110f77caaba01fbc6305d22e) and you'll know at what point it have error; or at least you can see the error code/message and search for it's information on what's wrong.